# Delete record from databricks DBFS

Tags: pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

I am trying to delete some records in Databricks Delta Lake that is located in DBFS. I only have path . Not saved as a table, is there any way to delete record from delta files?

Thank you

Comment: can you provide example of what you want to delete?

Comment: delete the file or record from a table?

Comment: I am trying to delete record from files not from a table

Answer (score 3):

Updated answer:

Delta Lake is able to perform deletes using the [DELETE FROM](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/delta-delete-from.html) command, so you just need to come with correct `WHERE` condition to match your record that you want to remove (put the real path instead of `<path-to-delta-table>`):

```sql
DELETE FROM delta.`<path-to-delta-table>` WHERE your_condition
```

First version of answer, before update:

[DBFS is the file system](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html), and items on it are files & directories.  You can remove files & directories either using `%fs rm file_name` ([docs](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#use-fs-magic-commands)), or corresponding `dbutils.fs.rm("file_name")` command in Python or Scala (see [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#dbutils)). You can even do it via [Databricks CLI](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#databricks-cli), directly from your computer or via REST API.

Another object in DBFS is a mount point, for which there are [special commands](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#mount-object-storage-to-dbfs).  You can unmount mount point if necessary